# Imprimir arreglo mediante AJAX y PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buenas ayer realice una parte del desarrollo con unos compañeros de aquí poder enviar datos a un div en lista a través de AJAX. Pero ahora me esta complicando la hora de imprimir en el div las opciones marcadas a través de un arreglo de PHP, la verdad no hecho muchos arreglos y se me esta complicando.

**FUNCIÓN AJAX**

```
$(function(){
      $(":checkbox").change(function(e){
        var brazos = '';
        var piernas = '';
        var zona = '';

        if ($('#BrazosE').is(':checked')) {
            brazos = $('#BrazosE').attr('id');
        }
        else {
            brazos = '';
        }

        if ($('#PiernasE').is(':checked')) {
            piernas = $('#PiernasE').attr('id');
        }
        else {
            piernas = '';
        }

        if ($('#ZonaI').is(':checked')) {
            zona = $('#ZonaI').attr('id');
        }
        else {
            zona = '';
        }

        $.ajax({
          url: "getZonas.php",
          type: "post",
          dataType: "html",
          data: {
            'brazos':brazos,
            'piernas':piernas,
            'zona':zona
          },
          success: function (resultado){
            $("#resva").html(resultado);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

**GETZONAS.PHP**

```
<?php
  $BrazosE =$_POST['brazos'];
  $piernas =$_POST['piernas'];
  $intima =$_POST['zona'];

  $pila = array("$BrazosE", "$piernas", "$intima");

  $resultado = compact("evento", "nada_aquí", $pila);
  //print_r($resultado);
  echo('<pre>');
   var_dump($resultado);
  echo('</pre>');
?>

<?php foreach ($resultado as $res => $pila): ?>
<ul>
 <li><?php echo $res; ?> <span class="pull-right">25€ <a href=""><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></span></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

El problema que solo me imprime brazosE, si hago clic en las otras no añade nada, además me gustaria decir que en lugar de que muestre `brazosE` poder decir yo que texto poner.

Comment: Quita los $ del array de literales que creas.

Comment: Al final estoy probando con JSON, mira si puedes aquí por favor https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/imprimir-resultado-mediante-json-y-ajax