# Imprimir resultado mediante JSON y AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

Buenas estoy intentando que al hacer check, mandar por con JSON y AJAX una respuesta y imprimir en un lista todo lo seleccionado. Pero no consigo mas que imprimirlo en la consola.

**El ajax**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
      // defines un arreglo
      var selected = [];
      $(":checkbox[name=opciones]").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          // agregas cada elemento.
          selected.push($(this).val());
        }
      });
      if (selected.length) {

        $.ajax({
          //cache: false,
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json', // importante para que
          data: {'selected': JSON.stringify(selected)}, // jQuery convierta el array a JSON
          url: "getZonas.php",
          success: function (data){
            $("#resva").html(data);
          }
        });
        // esto es solo para demostrar el json,
        // con fines didacticos
        //alert(JSON.stringify(selected));
        console.log(selected);

      } else
        alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

**getZonas.php**

```
$string = file_get_contents('./string.json');
$data = $_POST['selected'];

$json = json_decode($data);

foreach ($json as $info)
  {
  echo "items:". $info ."\n";
  }
  print_r($json)
```

**Div donde tiene que imprimir los resultados.**

```
 <div class="" id="resva"></div>
```

Es la primera vez que me aventuro con JSON y voy bastante perdido, gracias!

Comment: Ahora veo que lo imprime bien en la consola y también con el `print_r($json);` pero no me lo imprime los datos en el `div`

Comment: si pones un console.log(data); dentro del callback success que te sale?

Comment: creo que no llega nada, porque no sale nada :S @CarlosCompains

Comment: y si haces la peticion directa (metiendo la url en el navegador) a getZonas.php te sale algo?

Comment: Si me sale `null`

Comment: Entonces el problema por ahora no está en la parte de ajax si no en el php del servidor. pon un var_dump de $data

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88284/discussion-between-carlos-compains-and-miguel).

Comment: ok te escribi por ahi @CarlosCompains